# Image source winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, imagesource

Hi how can i set image source to an image in winforms?

my images are in Resources folder in the application only

I tried like this

PictureBox pb = new PictureBox();
 pb.Image = Image.FromFile("Resources/a.gif");

But it is showing file not found exception.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If the image is in your application's resources, you can do that :

```
pb.Image = Properties.Resources.a
```

Comment: Thank you verymuch this is what i'm searching for

Answer (score 1):

```
pictureBox1.Image = Properties.Resources.[image name];
```